Elasticsearch - All shards failed after weeks of stability
My company is running elasticsearch dockerized on production. It is pretty crucial component of our main application.
docker run --detach \
    --name elastic \
    --network xxx \
    --expose 9200 \
    --env TZ="Europe/Warsaw" \
    --volume /docker/elastic:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data \
    --restart always \
    --env discovery.type="single-node" \
    --env xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled="true" \
    --env xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode="none" \
    --env xpack.security.enabled="false" \
    --env xpack.security.enrollment.enabled="false" \
    --env indices.query.bool.max_clause_count="10240"  \
    --memory 8g \

After few weeks after initial deployment, in the middle of the day we faced a wall of errors that lasted few minutes disrupting our main services.

Error:

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [search_phase_execution_exception] all shards failed

When we were testing ES for months before it never happened.
We are using 2 indexes (1 shard each) they don't have much data (200mb both maybe) but they are queried often.
What could be a reason of that? Do elastic run some internal processes and if so can they be scheduled in a different time (night). Could remaking indexes into 2 or more shards help with that in the future, even though they are small ?
Any help appreciated.
I have tried nothing. Don't know how to reproduce this error.

You should provide more information about your Elastic Cluster it is better to share JVM memory pressure as well.
The first thing come to my mind is you are using to much Scroll API or Search After using (Point in a time) that would cause overflowing the memory and causing Elastic instability.
The best option would be to review the memory pressure and increase it if you are hitting around 80%.
You should increase number of nodes as well.

Sadly I do not have much information about jvm. I know we have plenty of spare memory and we never have more than 15-20% of cpu usage. Saying that I've stumbled on this small line in documentation. High availability (HA) clusters require at least three master-eligible nodes, at least two of which are not voting-only nodes. Such a cluster will be able to elect a master node even if one of the nodes fails. We are currently running just one node, so if there is any inner procces going on on it, it might be a problem. Will post update if I will get more data.

Running elastic with one node is not recommended and you should have atheist two nodes to keep your deployment healthy.

Since we added the additional cluster, the problem hasn't shown up again. I think we have resolved the issue.
